# Issue with mocha test debugging from typescript

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I trying to debug a mocha test but I have an issue and i don't know how can i solve it. I search on google before and on stackoverflow but without any success.

The error is :

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
source-map-support.js:444 error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.backend/test/textToSpeech/lib.ts(11,30): error TS2705: An async 
function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor. Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.backend/test/textToSpeech/lib.ts(12,27): error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor. Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
```

The tsconfig.json file looks like:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "watch": true,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "removeComments": true,
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": [
      "ES2015"
  ],
  "types": [
    "node",
    "pg-promise"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
  },
  "include": [
  "src/**/*"
 ],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "**/*.spec.ts"
 ]
}
```

And the vscode launch.json config is And the vscode launch.json config is

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Mocha Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/backend/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "args": [
          "--require", "ts-node/register",
          "-u",
          "tdd",
          "--timeout",
          "999999",
          "--colors",
          "${workspaceFolder}/backend/test/textToSpeech/lib.ts"
      ],
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
  }
```

The test file:

```
import {} from 'mocha'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import config from '../configuration'
import { TextToSpeechLib } from '../../src/libs/textToSpeech/'
var textToSpeach = new TextToSpeechLib(config)

var text = 'Hello world'


describe('TextToSpeach lib', async () => {
  it ('Convert text ...', async () => {
    console.log("==== =a= =s= a==")
    let resp = await textToSpeach.convertText(text);
    expect(resp.status).to.be.equal('success')
  })
})
```

I tried a lot of things. Is like the launcher don't load tsconfig. I tried to pass "--lib","'ES2015'" as arg in launcher config. 
Thank you.

Comment: I forgot the test:

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe try to add "ES2015.Promise" to the lib array in the tsconfig?

Comment: No. Not work . I tried this before after i searched on google. Looks like the tsconfig is not loaded. I tried to figure out how to specify to mocha to load tsconfg but with no success yet.

Comment: Maybe you should specify that you want to compile only the TypeScript test files? In my NPM package script I state the specific files to use for testing: "test": "mocha --timeout 10000 --colors --compilers ts:ts-node/register --exit ./tests/**/*.ts --full-trace --recursive", also I think that you can omit the async from the describe function

Comment: my tsconfig: 
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true,
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "allowJs": false,
      "outDir": "lib"
    }
  }

Comment: When I want to run code that uses `ES6 Promise`, I have to request the use of `es6` and `commonjs`, like this: `tsc myApp.ts --target es6 --module commonjs`.

Answer (score 4):

###### Update: This answer is old. There might be better ways to solve this problem by now. I have not tested it recently.

The error message clearly tells you what to do:

> Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your --lib option

Since we definitely do not want to supply our own definitons, we should go ahead and include 'ES2015' in the options.

#### How to do that?

All this ts-node suff is very involved. Somebody experienced in the matter could probably tell how to point to a specific `tsconfig`, I however can not. I suggest setting an environment variable to achieve this goal.

I digged into the source code to find out the neccessary env var is `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS`, meaning while invoking ts-node, `process.env` must have the attribute:

```json
TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={"lib": ["ES2015"], ...}
```

#### And how to do that?

When debugging using VS Code, you may achieve this goal by adding the following to your configuration:

```json
"env": {"TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS":"{\"lib\": [\"ES2015\"]}"}
```

When you want to run your tests, e.g. using `npm test`, you can add this option to the environment vars prior to running the test script using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

I ended up writing something like this in my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS=\"{\\\"lib\\\": [\\\"ES2015\\\"]}\" mocha --require ts-node/register path/to/test(s).ts"
}
```

**Note** - Triple backslashses are intentional

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer. I will try your solution because i didn;t solve the issue. but I just ignored for the short time.

Comment: @dudufux Please consider responding whether this solved your problem, and accept the answer if it did.

Comment: Adding the TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS env var as specified fixed the problem for me.  I set it in by bash profile but should work either way

Comment: This is kind of problematic, as I've noticed that instead of using my tsconfig build location, its just dumping compiled .js files into my src directories.  This may not be an acceptable solution for that reason

Comment: @Steve you can set the env variable directly in your launch.json: "env": {
            "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "path/to/tsconfig.json"
        }.  This would cause it to honor your tsconfig and place the files in the correct location.  If you need a test specific configuration, this would also allow you to specify a tsconfig.test.json file that would exclusively be used in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the triple-backslash solution, helped me as it would throw me a **SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1** error before. Makes perfect sense now.